# Does Windows Phone delay or batch HTTP requests? Seeing 600ms request delay to a server on the same LAN

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone, windows-phone-7

I am developing a Windows Phone app that communicates with a server on home LAN over wifi, and I ran into a show stopper: an average round trip time for a tiny HTTP request inside LAN is 600-800ms.

This only happens with a standalone phone. If the phone is connected to PC running Zune the phone starts talking through Zune and the response time drops from 600ms to 20ms (!).

I wrote a small repro program that sends HTTP request every 100ms and ran Wireshark trace.
The trace shows that the server responds right away. It is the phone that delays requests and sends three to five requests at a time as a batch roughly once a second.

More info:

My program is using HttpWebRequest not WebClient.
I tried to spawn threads for each request, no luck. 
This happens on WP7 release and on Mango.
The same thing whether I run off  my work or home Wifi.
A low level implementation using socket API in Mango exhibits same behavior.

I have seen other posts on App Hub with the same issue. Please help clarify why this is happening.

Comment: more info: a friend of mine suggested this was some kind of throttling mechanism for frequent requests. I tried the same test with just one request. Seeing the same response range with a single request too.

Comment: Could you provide the code you are using to setup the requests?

Comment: The code does not fit into a comment. It is a basic HttpWebRequest with BeginGetResponse. I pass DateTime.Now value in AsyncState to measure response time.

Comment: I'm starting to think this might be a driver issue. What type of phone? And anyone else seeing this problem, what type of phone? And if you're prepared to publish the repro project and corresponding server repro project, I would like to test this on my own hardware. If it's hardware specific, that's a phone vendor thing. If not, we can send the repros to the WP7 team.

Comment: Here is zip file with my repro project:
http://www.mediafire.com/?rhxh6n4kdrt5481

Connect to a PC, run Zune, point the app to a local http server and see short roundtrip time. Then disconnect and run again. You should see a jump in latency.

I am using Samsung Focus. I have seen similar posts about HTC phones.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps another experiment will help.  Put your phone on charge and use the WiFi to send your messages.  I suspect this batching is a result of a battery saving feature.

Comment: I thought of battery saving too. It does the same whether charging through PC USB or power outlet. Only having PC USB with Zune running speeds things up drastically as Zune acts as a bridge.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, cellular networks link layer protocols are bursty so they can virtualise and run more connections than there are transponders. I suspect this is the root of your symptoms.

Comment: This is on wifi connection not 3G. Maybe the bursty nature of cell network implementation is leaking into their Wifi implementation as well. I just find it hard to believe that 600ms delays on Wifi are not widely known to community or documented by Microsoft. I hope I am missing something

Comment: Presumably you're using DHCP, check your default gateways, perhaps you have 2 & the first is timing out.